# Python code explanation for stationary distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have got this code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig 
transition_mat = np.matrix([
    [.95, .05, 0., 0.],\
    [0., 0.9, 0.09, 0.01],\
    [0., 0.05, 0.9, 0.05],\
    [0.8, 0., 0.05, 0.15]])

S, U = eig(transition_mat.T)
stationary = np.array(U[:, np.where(np.abs(S - 1.) < 1e-8)[0][0]].flat)
stationary = stationary / np.sum(stationary)

>>> print stationary
[ 0.34782609  0.32608696  0.30434783  0.02173913]
```

But I can't understand the line:

```
stationary = np.array(U[:, np.where(np.abs(S - 1.) < 1e-8)[0][0]].flat)
```

Can anyone explain the part: `U[:, np.where(np.abs(S - 1.) < 1e-8)[0][0]].flat` ?

I know that the routine returns `S`: eigenvalue, `U` : eigenvector. I need to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 1. I have wrote the code below:

```
for i in range(len(S)):
    if S[i] == 1.0:
        j = i

 matrix = np.array(U[:, j].flat)
```

I am getting output:

```
:  [ 0.6144763   0.57607153  0.53766676  0.03840477]
```

but it does not give the same output. why?!

Comment: Hm... It *looks* like it's grabbing elements out of U where the corresponding element in S has a value of 1... but I'm not sure what that `[0][0]` is for.  It then flattens the whole thing into a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for answering. can u please tell me how does this code : where(np.abs(S-1.) < 1e-8) supposed to work?

Comment: Have you tried it on a simple example? Read any of the documentation? What *precisely* is confusing you about it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes I m still trying. I have updated the question with my code. please check. thanks.

Comment: The margin here's too small to write down everything in full.  Just read the documentation for `numpy.where` carefully, and try out the examples! ;)

Comment: Can't edit comment, so copied: It finds the one that is closest to unity, based on the criterion of "difference in absolute value should be less than 1e-8".   The `where` call returns a tuple containing arrays, where each array corresponds to a dimension, and such arrays contain the indices where the predicate evaluates to `True`.  The first `[0]` retrieves the 1st tuple element (there's only one dimension in S, so this is what you can do), which is an array, and the 2nd `[0]` retrieves the 1st element in this array (if multiplicity of this eigenvalue is one, this is just what you want).

Comment: Also, in your own code snippet, you got the index, saved it to `j`, and you didn't use `j` at all :(.  That's the 1st mistake.  The 2nd is to compare floating point number like `V[i] == 1`, which is dangerous due to not accommodating for floating-point errors.

Comment: @CongMa, thanks a lot for your help. I have updated my code. can u please check where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @dont_give_up for one thing you're still doing `==` comparison for floating point (and complex!) numbers. Secondly you're comparing apples to oranges.  In the 1st version the result is normalised by the sum (and I wonder why this is necessary), and in the 2nd version it's not.

Comment: @CongMa, thanks so much. I hv got it finally. please copy-paste ur comment as an answer so that I can select that.

Comment: @dont_give_up I was simply paraphrasing the documentation of `numpy.where` so it doesn't quite deserve a full-fledged answer.  As an exercise you can write your own, clearer explanation of everything in that line containing `where()` as an answer, using the doc as source material, and accept that ;)

Comment: The output is different since you still need to normalize.

Answer (score 16):

## How to find a stationary distribution.

Ok, I came to this post looking to see if there was a built-in method to find the stationary distribution.  It looks like there's not.  So, for anyone coming in from Google, this is how I would find the stationary distribution in this circumstance:

```
import numpy as np

#note: the matrix is row stochastic.
#A markov chain transition will correspond to left multiplying by a row vector.
Q = np.array([
    [.95, .05, 0., 0.],
    [0., 0.9, 0.09, 0.01],
    [0., 0.05, 0.9, 0.05],
    [0.8, 0., 0.05, 0.15]])

#We have to transpose so that Markov transitions correspond to right multiplying by a column vector.  np.linalg.eig finds right eigenvectors.
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(Q.T)
evec1 = evecs[:,np.isclose(evals, 1)]

#Since np.isclose will return an array, we've indexed with an array
#so we still have our 2nd axis.  Get rid of it, since it's only size 1.
evec1 = evec1[:,0]

stationary = evec1 / evec1.sum()

#eigs finds complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors, so you'll want the real part.
stationary = stationary.real
```

## What that one weird line is doing.

Let's break that line into parts:

```
#Find the eigenvalues that are really close to 1.
eval_close_to_1 = np.abs(S-1.) < 1e-8

#Find the indices of the eigenvalues that are close to 1.
indices = np.where(eval_close_to_1)

#np.where acts weirdly.  In this case it returns a 1-tuple with an array of size 1 in it.
the_array = indices[0]
index = the_array[0]

#Now we have the index of the eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.
stationary = U[:, index]

#For some really weird reason, the person that wrote the code
#also does this step, which is completely redundant.
#It just flattens the array, but the array is already 1-d.
stationary = np.array(stationary.flat)
```

If you compress all these lines of code into one line you get `stationary = np.array(U[:, np.where(np.abs(S-1.)<1e-8)[0][0]].flat)`

If you remove the redundant stuff you get `stationary = U[:, np.where(np.abs(S - 1.) < 1e-8)[0][0]]`

## Why your code gives a different stationary vector.

As [@Forzaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1479342/forzaa) pointed out, your vector cannot represent a vector of probabilities because it does not sum to 1.  If you divide it by its sum, you'll get the vector the original code snippet has.

Just add this line:

```
stationary = matrix/matrix.sum()
```

Your stationary distribution will then match.

Comment: I agree... & [here](https://ninavergara2.medium.com/calculating-stationary-distribution-in-python-3001d789cd4b) is brief explanation *How to calculate stationary distribution*

Answer (score 0):

```
stationary = np.array(U[:,np.where(np.abs(S-1.) < 1e-8)[0][0]].flat)
```

This piece of code is searching for elements in **U** who's corresponding eigen value - 1 is less than 1e-8

Comment: meaning S=1, 1e-8 is just the precision tolerance of the equality comparison of floating point numbers

Answer (score 0):

actually, just do a simple while iteration. I'll use a random P as an example

```
def get_stationary(n):
    row = n
    pi = np.full((1, row), 1 / row)
    T = np.array([[1/4,1/2,1/4],
                  [1/3,0,2/3],
                  [1/2,0,1/2]])
    while True:
        new_pi = np.dot(pi, T)
        if np.allclose(pi, new_pi):
            return pi 
            break
        pi = new_pi
print(get_stationary(3))
```